# Can't replace selected regex number by type next number

Tags: c#, regex, wpf, xaml, textbox

I'm using xaml `<TextBox/>` with code behind which contains event `PreviewTextchanged` named *NumberValidationTextBox* and event `TextChanged` named *OnTextChanged*:

```
    public void NumberValidationTextBox(object sender, TextCompositionEventArgs e)
    {
        Regex regex = new Regex("^-?[0-9]*[\\.,]?[0-9]?[0-9]?$");
        var futureText = $"{(sender as TextBox).Text}{e.Text}";
        e.Handled = !regex.IsMatch(futureText);

    }
    private void OnTextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var myInput = sender as TextBox;
        myInput.Text = myInput.Text.Replace(",", ".").Trim();
        myInput.CaretIndex = myInput.Text.Length;
    }
```

Problem is when typed number is for example: `123.23`, and I select the number by click and mouse drag and try to replace it by type next number - it don't changes, because regex is blocking it. Only using Backspace is the solution in this case. So I want to change the selected text when the TextBox is filled.

All detais above and here link with ss: https://i.ibb.co/z7rPfpj/123.png

How to fix it?
Thanks.

Comment: what you describes is what he events does t..i suggest you to precise exactly what you want, its seems you have to revise all your logic....

Comment: Regex is working. I can't replace the typed number ex.  ```123.99``` by selecting the number and type other number (without using backspace).

Comment: Here is screenshot with one selected for better understand what I mean: [link](https://i.ibb.co/z7rPfpj/123.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your method `NumberValidationTextBox` by:

```
    public void NumberValidationTextBox(object sender, TextCompositionEventArgs e)
    {
        Regex regex = new Regex("^-?[0-9]*[\\.,]?[0-9]?[0-9]?$");
        var tb = sender as TextBox;
        var futureText = "";
        if (tb.SelectedText != "")
        {
            futureText = tb.Text.Replace(tb.SelectedText, e.Text);
            e.Handled = !regex.IsMatch(futureText);
            return;
        }

        futureText = tb.Text + e.Text;
        e.Handled = !regex.IsMatch(futureText);
    }
```

you test SelectedText to check if some chars are selected

Comment: Will test it today. Why people giving -1 rating?

Comment: its the life...nevermind!!